# MySQL MYISAM database corrupted - deleted rows

Tags: mysql, sql, myisam

I have a database files from my old server and tried to get it working on my local PC. Unfortunately it looks like 3 rows of my table is missing. Those 3 rows are really important to me. If i run REPAIR, it just changes files size of .MYD and .MYI files and those 3 rows are gone forever.

Is there a way how to tell MYSQL, that deleted blocks are not actually deleted?

```
warning     Size of indexfile is: 659456      Should be: 40652...
warning     Size of datafile is: 413636       Should be: 38130...
warning     Found 32332 deleted space.   Should be 0
warning     Found 3 deleted blocks       Should be: 0
warning     Found 79 key parts. Should be: 76
```

EDIT: In my .MYD file are all data, but I don't know how to get them because they seem to have some weird encoding set.

Comment: Does the data still appear in the old DB?

Comment: Old DB does not exist. I have only backup in a form of .MYD a.MYI files. Anyway I am extracting data from .MYD file, but it does seem to contain data to all fields.